# Virtualising servers on Mac OS

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox, vmware-server, parallels

I need to virtualise Ubuntu 24/7 on my Mac. Is there a lite virtualisation piece of software that allows me to run it discretely? I do not want an interface... I will manage via SSH... I have been using VirtualBox but it always insists on having a window open... can I run a guest 
 OS as a service?? VMWare server looks suitable but it's not available for the Mac... :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VirtualBox is still your friend. You can launch the VM's headless.

Try running the following in Terminal.app:

```
VBoxHeadless --help
```

It seems that you can also do:

```
VBoxManage startvm <vmname> --type headless
```